# File pattern for Publish Pipeline Artifact in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

Recently just built an **Azure Pipeline** where in one stage there are different zip files in the artifact staging directory. What I'm trying to achieve is publish to the *drop* folder ***all*** the zip files from the staging folder with `PublishPipelineArtifact` task.

I have 2 archived zip files in artifact staging directory:

1. *$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip*
2. *$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/cli_scripts_$(Build.BuildId).zip*

In my *azure-pipelines.yml* file please find the publish task:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish pipeline artifacts'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**
```

This gives the following error:

> [error] Path does not exist: d:\a\1\a**

I have already tried with the following as well but none of them working:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip
```

***Question:***

What is the pattern for `targetPath` to move all the zip files from that folder?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What finally resolved the issue is including a pattern with `archiveFilePatterns` in the task and not combining with the `targetPath` as I originally tried.

The solution which worked well is the following:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish pipeline artifacts'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/
    archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip'
```

The official documentation does not really states this but it was giving the idea using the pattern attribute: [Publish and download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task)

[image]

I hope that helps someone in the future.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore :/

Comment: This has just helped me greatly, was also trying to put a full path and file glob into the targetPath. Not obvious that you need to separate out the two. Having said that, archiveFilePatterns doesn't seem to be recognised and is undocumented, so I'm not sure it's doing anything. Perhaps just removing the glob from the `targetPath` is the fix although of course this doesn't allow filtering

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.artifactignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops) file to filter what the `PublishPipelineArtifact` task can see. Make sure the file is **in the folder that you're publishing**, as mentioned here:
[image]