# Pipeline Artifact not Downloading with Stages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, artifacts, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have recently upgraded my YAML pipeline to include Stages, since this has happened the build artifacts are not downloading in a later stage task. For the life of me I cant figure out why.

Please see my YAML Code Bellow with an explanation on how my pipeline works.

First I have the main pipeline that calls the template yaml files.

`mainpipeline.yml`

```html
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources: 
  repositories: 
  - repository: Terraform
    name: VALUE/Terraform
    path:
    - include: /Terraform
    type: git 
    ref: main #branch name
  - repository: Website
    name: VALUE/Website
    path:
    - include: /Website 
    type: git 
    ref: newartifactpipeline #branch name
  - repository: AuthenticationServer
    name: VALUE/AuthenticationServer
    path:
    - include: /AuthenticationServer
    type: git 
    ref: VALUE #branch name
  
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:

- stage: build_website_files
  displayName: Building Main Website Files
  jobs:
  - job: build_main_website
    steps: 
     - checkout: Website
  - template: buildartifact.yml@website
    parameters:
      #vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      buildConFiguration: $(buildConfiguration)
      project: Website.csproj
      artifactName: Website

- stage: build_authenticationserver_files
  displayName: Building AuthenticationServer Website Files
  jobs:
  - job: build_authenticationserver_website 
    steps: 
     - checkout: AuthenticationServer
  - template: buildartifact.yml@AuthenticationServer
    parameters:
     # vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      buildConFiguration: $(buildConfiguration)
      project: AuthenticationServer.csproj
      artifactName: AuthenticationServer
      
- stage: run_terraform_pre_build 
  displayName: Building Terraform Applications and Deploying Web Apps 
  jobs:
  - job: building_terraform_applications
    steps: 
     - checkout: Terraform
  - template: /VALUE/runterraform.yml@Terraform
    parameters: 
      terraformWorkingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VALUE'
      serviceConnection: 'VALUE'
      azureSubscription: 'VALUE'
      appconnectionname: 'VALUE'
      backendresourcegroupname: 'VALUE'
      backendstorageaccountname: 'VALUE'
      backendcontainername: 'VALUE'
      RG: 'RG_Example'
      azureLocation: 'UK South'
      terraformVersion: '1.0.4'
      artifactName: 'Website'

- stage: run_terraform_post_build 
  displayName: Apply Post Build Settings 
  jobs:
  - job: apply_post_build_settings
    steps: 
     - checkout: Terraform 
  - template: /Terraform/PostBuild/runterraformpostbuild.yml@Terraform
    parameters: 
        terraformWorkingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VALUE/PostBuild'
        serviceConnection: 'VALUE'
        azureSubscription: 'VALUE'
        appconnectionname: 'VALUE'
        backendresourcegroupname: ''VALUE''
        backendstorageaccountname: 'VALUE'
        backendcontainername: 'VALUE'
        RG: 'RG_Example'
        azureLocation: 'UK South'
        terraformVersion: '1.0.4'
        artifactName: 'Website'
```

The first stage builds and calls this build artifact template yaml file, that does successfully publish the artifact file, yaml code below:

Please see screenshot bellow as proof:

[image]

`buildartifact.yml`

```html
parameters:

- name: buildConfiguration
  type: string
  default: 'Release'

- name: project
  type: string
  default: 'Website.csproj'

- name: artifactName
  type: string
  default: 'Website'

- name: vmImage
  type: string
  default: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: build_website 
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
  steps:
  - checkout: Website
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' 
        dir

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**/${{ parameters.project }}'
        # Node.js tool installer
        # Finds or downloads and caches the specified version spec of Node.js and adds it to the PATH
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Install Node .js'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14.17.3' 
      force32bit: false # Optional
      checkLatest: false # Optional

  - script: |
       npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.3
       npm install
    displayName: 'npm install'  
  
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm run build'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: ClientApp
      customCommand: 'build'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/${{ parameters.project }}'
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}' 

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet restore unit tests 
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: 'UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet Test
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: 'UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Application'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/${{ parameters.project }}'
      arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --output $(Pipeline.Workspace)/website/'
  
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/website/'
      artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

With this yaml for the `PublishPipelineArtifact` task I have tried the following env variables for pipleines: `pipeline.workspace` and `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`

Yet both have not worked in the later stage where the final yaml file tries to download the pipeline artifact see yaml code bellow:

`runterraformanddownloadartifact.yml`

```html
parameters:
  - name: terraformWorkingDirectory
    type: string
    default: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform
  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string
    default: value
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
    default: value
  - name: appconnectionname
    type: string
    default: value
  - name: backendresourcegroupname   
    type: string
    default: DevOpsTerraform
  - name: backendstorageaccountname
    type: string
    default: value
  - name: backendcontainername
    type: string
    default: value
  - name: RG
    type: string
    default: RG_Example
  - name: azureLocation
    type: string
    default: UK South
  - name: terraformVersion
    type: string
    default: 1.0.4
  - name: artifactName
    type: string
    default: Website

jobs:
  - job: Run_Terraform
    displayName: Installing and Running Terraform
    steps:
      - checkout: Terraform
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: install
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: '${{ parameters.terraformVersion }}'
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' 
            dir
      - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: init
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: init
          backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.backendresourcegroupname }}'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '${{ parameters.backendstorageaccountname }}'
          backendAzureRmContainerName: '${{ parameters.backendcontainername }}'
          backendAzureRmKey: terraform.tfstate
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: plan
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: plan
          commandOptions: '-input=false'
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: apply
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: apply
          commandOptions: '-input=false -auto-approve'
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'

  - job: Put_artifacts_into_place
    displayName: Putting_artifacts_into_place
    dependsOn: Run_Terraform
    steps:
      - checkout: Website
      - checkout: AuthenticationServer

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download Build Artifacts
        inputs:
          artifact: '${{ parameters.artifactName }}'
          patterns: /website/**/*.zip
          path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/website/

      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: VALUE'
        inputs:
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/website/**/*.zip
          azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
          ConnectedServiceName: '${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}'
          appName: VALUE
          ResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.RG}}'

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download Build Artifacts
        inputs:
          artifact: '${{ parameters.artifactName}}'
          patterns: /authsrv/**/*.zip
          path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/authsrv/
          
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: VALUE'
        inputs:
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/authsrv/**/*.zip
          azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
          ConnectedServiceName: '${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}'
          appName: VALUE
          ResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.RG}}'
```

Essentially the first pipeline calls these two pipelines which are wrapped in Stages. Before they were not wrapped in stages and this pipeline worked well. Since moving it to stages I have had the issue where the task: `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` completes but downloads nothing. Please see screen shot bellow:

[image]

The error I am getting at the end of the pipeline is:
`##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: /home/vsts/work/1/website/**/*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.`

I have tried the following solutions without success:

[File pattern for Publish Pipeline Artifact in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300400/file-pattern-for-publish-pipeline-artifact-in-azure-devops)

[how to use PublishPipelineArtifact@1 with build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430412/how-to-use-publishpipelineartifact1-with-build-script)

And consulted MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Have you tried different patterns for the download? looking at the log screenshot it states "Filtered 0 files from the Mimimatch filters supplied" I would suggest you to try once with this pattern `**/*.zip` once to see the downloads and then manipulate your pattern as per your needs.

Comment: I have tried that, I am just trying something now I'm not sure if it was making the website folder to begin with, so if this works then I have found the issue.

Comment: I tried to replicate your scenario in my setup and download went fine. The only difference was in the log, mine actually filtered 1 file which was 0 in your case.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you for taking the time to look at the scenario.